# Sort, text page based on 5th column out of 6 columns being troubled with as the first column has sub columns

Tags: bash, sorting

How to sort, by CLI utility or Bash codes, a plain text page, based on 5th column out of 6 columns regarded by human. but not by machine, as the first column has 1-4 sub columns, means 1, 2, 3, or 4 words (non-space strings),  with its starting word is always started with alphabet but not always for the other words if any, so the text page would have arbitrarily between 6 to 9 columns, and the rest columns is only one single word i.e. one non-space string ?

the top titles 1,2.. 6 is aiding illustration

```
    1                 2   3   4   5  6



foo bar               x    y   z   9  z
foo                   z    x   y   3  z
foo bar baz           k    l   m   1  n
```

...
so on

Comment: What is the expected output? Also what have you tried and where did it failed?

Comment: what's the delimiter between words in the 1st column ... a space? what's the delimiter between the rest of the columns ... tab, variable number of spaces or fixed width?

Comment: `<text.page awk '$0=$(NF-1)"\t"$0' | sort -n -k1,1 | cut -f 2-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sort` had an option to count the sorting keys from the end of the records your problem would be simple: sort on the second to last column, something like `sort -sk-2,-2` where negative keys would be counted from the end. Unfortunately `sort` does not support this kind of things yet.

But we can reorder the columns with `sed`, such that the two last columns becomes the two first, sort on only the first column (`sort -sk1,1`), and reorder again with `sed`. Example with GNU `sed`, output prefixed with `-|` :

```
sed -E 's/(.*\s)(\S+\s+\S.*)/\2 \1/' file.txt |
  sort -sk1,1 | sed -E 's/^(\S+\s+\S+) (.*)/\2\1/'
-| foo bar baz           k    l   m   1  n
-| foo                   z    x   y   3  z
-| foo bar               x    y   z   9  z
```

With any POSIX `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.*[[:space:]]\)\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+[^[:space:]].*\)/\2 \1/' file.txt |
  sort -sk1,1 |
  sed 's/^\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+[^[:space:]]\+\) \(.*\)/\2\1/'
-| foo bar baz           k    l   m   1  n
-| foo                   z    x   y   3  z
-| foo bar               x    y   z   9  z
```